# How to display another table by clicking a button that is inside the table?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

```html
<html>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for members..." />
  <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
</body>
</html>



<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: middle;    
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showHide(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none') {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1">
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("could not connect");
mysql_select_db("vauban") or die("could not find database");
$output = '';

if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
  $searchq = $_POST['search'];
  $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info3 WHERE FirstName LIKE '%$searchq%' OR LastName LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("could not search!");
  $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0) {
       $output = 'There was no search results!';
  }else{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $id = $row['Id'];
        echo"<td>". $row['Id']."</td>";
        echo"<td>". $row['FirstName']."</td>";
        echo"<td>". $row['LastName']. "</td>";
        echo"<td>". $row['PhoneNumber']. "</td>";
        echo"<td> <button onclick=\"showHide('id'); return false;\">". $row['CompanyName']. "</button></td>";
        echo"<td> <a href ='view.php?Id=$id'>Edit</a>";
        echo"<td> <a href ='del.php?Id=$id'><center>Delete</center></a>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $CompanyName=$row['CompanyName'];
    }
  }
}

?>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
function showHide(id) {
$CompanyName=$row['CompanyName'];
if ($CompanyName = "Company A") {
<?php
echo "<table id='test1' style='width:50%' align='right'>";
include("db.php");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company where no = '1'");
while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        $id = $test['No'];
        echo "<th rowspan='1'>Company name</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['CompanyName']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Location</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Location']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Found</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Found']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Website</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Website']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th rowspan='3'>Contact</th>";
        echo "<th>Email</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Email']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Phone</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Phone']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Fax</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Fax']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<br>";           
      }
      mysql_close($conn);
      ?>
</table>
        }
else if ($CompanyName = "Company B") {
<?php
echo "<table id='test2' style='width:50%' align='right'>";
include("db.php");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company where no = '2'");
while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        $id = $test['No'];  
        echo "<th rowspan='1'>Company name</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['CompanyName']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Location</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Location']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Found</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Found']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Website</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Website']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th rowspan='3'>Contact</th>";
        echo "<th>Email</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Email']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Phone</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Phone']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Fax</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Fax']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<br>";           
      }
      mysql_close($conn);
      ?>
</table>
    }
    else if ($CompanyName= "Company C") {
<?php
echo "<table id='test3' style='width:50%' align='right'>";
include("db.php");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company where no = '3'");
while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        $id = $test['No'];  
        echo "<th rowspan='1'>Company name</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['CompanyName']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Location</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Location']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Found</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Found']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Website</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Website']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th rowspan='3'>Contact</th>";
        echo "<th>Email</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Email']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Phone</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Phone']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Fax</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Fax']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<br>";           
      }
      mysql_close($conn);
      ?>
</table>
    }
    else if ($CompanyName = "Company D") {
<?php
echo "<table id='test4' style='width:50%' align='right'>";
include("db.php");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company where no = '4'");
while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        $id = $test['No'];  
        echo "<th rowspan='1'>Company name</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['CompanyName']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Location</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Location']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Found</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Found']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Website</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Website']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th rowspan='3'>Contact</th>";
        echo "<th>Email</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Email']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Phone</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Phone']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Fax</th>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>". $test['Fax']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<br>";           
      }
      mysql_close($conn);
      ?>
    }
    else {
        alert("No such company exist...");
    }
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

My table:

[image]

and what I want to display when I click on one of the button:

[image]

I just want to display another table when I click on one of the column and it has to be accurate (e.g. click Company C to get information of Company C).

Tried using `function()` ---> fail

Tried using `if else`   ---> fail

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: How did you try? AJAX? Form? What happened?

Comment: My code is a mess! It have, html.php,javascript and mysql in it

Comment: But at least include it in your post.

Comment: Just added my code :/

Comment: this `if ($CompanyName = "Company A")` and `else if ($CompanyName = "Company B")` and others are failing you. You are assigning `=` instead of comparing `==` and might be the main cause why it's failing you.

Comment: You also need to understand that php is executed on the server first, and then the javascript is executed on the client side **after** the php has been processed. So your code inside the `<script type="text/javascript"> function showHide(id) { ... }` is not able to do what you want to do. You need to either save all this data in a javascript object, or use ajax.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
function showHide(id) {
$CompanyName=$row['CompanyName'];
if ($CompanyName = "Company A") {` you're injecting PHP into JS, so that too is failing you. as is this is JS `else {
        alert("No such company exist...");
    }` and won't work inside PHP. and others inside script tags.

Comment: You want something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Logan_Wayne/stjdj61p/)?

Comment: @NkylveSteinerEvlykn Are you planning to use JQuery?

Comment: @LoganWayne thanks, i guess i can work on that

Comment: @NkylveSteinerEvlykn - Reminder: I used [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) (javascript library) on that example. BTW, how do you relate the `info3` table to the `company` table?

Comment: @LoganWayne I didn't connect them together, just want to display a table from company when i click a button on info3...wait i need to connect them?

Comment: So you can distinguish what company a user is. You will just index it to the `company` table. For example: `info3.CompanyName = company.CompanyName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) in order to achieve what you want.

**Reminder**: `mysql_*` is already [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php), so you should consider [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead.

First is, you need to list down your data in a table from `info3` table, assuming that `company` table has `CompanyName` column in order to connect it to your `info3` table's `CompanyName` column.

```
echo '<td> <button class="company_button">'.$row['CompanyName'].'</button></td>';
```

And create a `div` space for returned data of the clicked button.

```
<div id="company_desc_div"></div>
```

Then we can create a script using jQuery (javascript library) which you can download [here](http://jquery.com/download/).

```
$(document).on("click", ".company_button", function(){ /* WHEN A BUTTON IS CLICKED */

  var company_desc = $(this).text(); /* GET WHAT COMPANY IS IT */

  $.ajax({ /* START AJAX */
    type: "POST", /* METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
    url: "get_company_info.php", /* FILE WHERE WE WILL PROCESS THE PASSED ON DATA */
    data: { "company_desc": company_desc }, /* DATA TO BE PASSED ON */
    success: function(result){ /* GET THE RETURNED DATA FROM get_company_info.php */
      $("#company_desc_div").html(result); /* PUT THE RETURNED DATA TO company_desc_div DIV */
    }
  });

});
```

As you might notice, we pass the data of the clicked button to `get_company_info.php`, so lets create that file:

```
<?php

  /* ESTABLISH YOUR CONNECTION */
  $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "vauban");

  /* CHECK CONNECTION */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }

  if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT CompanyName, Location, Found, Website, Email, Phone, Fax FROM company WHERE CompanyName = ?")){ /* PREPARE THE STATEMENT */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST["company_desc"]); /* BIND THE PASSED ON DATA TO THE SELECT QUERY */
    $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE QUERY */
    $stmt->bind_result($companyname, $location, $found, $website, $email, $phone, $fax); /* BIND THE RESULT TO THESE VARIABLES */
    $stmt->fetch(); /* FETCH THE RESULTS */

    /* WHAT YOU ECHO IS WHAT WILL BE RETURNED TO THE AJAX REQUEST */
    echo '<table>
            <tr>
              <th>Company name</th>
              <td colspan="3">'.$companyname.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Location</th>
              <td colspan="3">'.$location.'</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Found</th>
              <td colspan="3">'.$found.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Website</th>
              <td colspan="3">'.$website.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th rowspan="3">Contact</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <td>'.$email.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Phone</th>
              <td colspan="3">'.$phone.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Fax</th>
              <td colspan="3">'.$fax.'</td>
            </tr>
          </table>';

    $stmt->close();

  } /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */

?>
```

What we echo from this file is what will be returned to the AJAX request.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code! but there is still one error though..that 'inspect element' thing tell me it is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier coming from this line   'success: function(result){' but i think i can manage that, thanks a lot!!

Comment: @NkylveSteinerEvlykn - you found the error? It is because I forgot `,` after the `data:{}`. Look at my updated answer, I just put `,` at the end of `data: {}` inside the ajax.

Comment: It is out!! It works! After I fix that undefine variable:con on get_company_info.php(replacing $mysqli with $con) It finally out! Thank you again for this! :D

Comment: @NkylveSteinerEvlykn Oh yeah! That also! I forgot it.